# Images no longer display on wordpress pages

Tags: wordpress, image

After installing and configuring a few plugins to optimize the cache and increase my score, my images refuse to appear on client pages. Even in the library they are not displayed. however the links of his images are very real and they lead to the images in the folder. I then uninstalled these plugins and clear the cache but still nothing.
Here are the plugins:

- GT metrix
- WP fastest cache
- Shortpixel image optimize
- Lazy load - optimize images

Comment: This is not the right place to ask this question. Try https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

> Lazy load - optimize images

Hey Giovani, this is probably messing up something, you should just remove it. (Just a wild guess, with no code nor link to your website, no wizards tricks)
**Lazyloading has since been incorporated as a default feature on most major web browsers.**

You can use `loading="lazy"` in you image tag `<img src"" alt="" loading="lazy" >`

No library needed, by using `loading="lazy"` if an image need to be lazy loaded, the browser knows it and will to it by default

https://web.dev/native-lazy-loading/
https://caniuse.com/#feat=loading-lazy-attr

Hope this will help you

Comment: Thank you for your help. The point is, I am using wordpress and I am new to it. How to automatically add the loading = "lazy" for all images?

Comment: Manually in your images tags in your template.